# Python OptsParse Attribute Checking.. i think

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, arguments

I have an opts parse.
ex.:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("ablah, dest = 'a',\
    action = 'store', nargs=2)
parser.add_option("bblah, dest = 'b',\
    action = 'store', nargs=2)
parser.add_option("cblah, dest = 'c',\
    action = 'store', nargs=2)
```

now I would get a dictionary. The problem it is an attribute of opts.
So I tried:

```
for x in opts.__dict__.iterkeys():
    if x = 'bblah':
        callfunction1(opts.bblah[0],opts.bblah[1])
    if x = 'ablah':
        callfunction2(opts.ablah[0],opts.ablah[1])
    if x = 'cblah':
        callfunction3(opts.cblah[0],opts.cblah[1])
```

the problem here is 2 fold.

1. i have multiple elements in the opts tuple/dictionary thing.
2. how do i check to make sure these objects have values. otherwise i get that you cannot call values with None. I need this "checking" to be done here, since it will cause some serious errors if i do it in the function

I know someone said the approach is usually leap than ask for forgiveness, but I would like to do checking first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly but maybe this could give you a hint:

```
# map option name to function
func_map = {'ablah': ablah,
        'bblah': bblah,
        'cblah': cblah}

# filter out the options without argument
# this may be redundant, optparse can make proper validations
selected = filter(lambda x: x[1], opts.__dict__.items())

for k, v in selected:
    func_map[k](*v)
```